# python 2.7 - argparse: parameters to optional arguments

Tags: python, argparse

I have the following Code Snippet.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.set_defaults(func=lambda x: parser.print_usage())

parser.add_argument('-o', '--overview', help="print overview",
                    action='store_true')

parser.add_argument('-a', '--add', help='add sudo item', nargs='*',
                    dest="ldap_attrs")
parser.add_argument('dn, object_class, attributes', nargs='*')

parser.add_argument('-d', '--delete', help='delete sudo item', dest='action',
                    action='store_const', const=deleteItem)
parsed_args = parser.parse_args()
```

It prints out the following:

```
usage: sudoadm.py [-h] [-o] [-a [LDAP_ATTRS [LDAP_ATTRS ...]]] [-d]

                  [dn, object_class, attributes [dn, object_class, attributes ...]]

positional arguments:
  dn, object_class, attributes

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -o, --overview        print overview
  -a [LDAP_ATTRS [LDAP_ATTRS ...]], --add [LDAP_ATTRS [LDAP_ATTRS ...]]
                        add sudo item
  -d, --delete          delete sudo item
```

I want the positional Arguments as Input Parametes to the -a Argument
(eg: -a dn, object_class, attributes), and if possible the positional Paramters printed in the help message instead of LDAP_ATTRS ( eg: -a [dn, object_class, attributes])?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When defining a positional, the call is:

```
parser.add_argument(dest, nargs='*', help='...', ...)
```

That is, the one non-keyword argument is the `dest`, the name of the attribute in `args`.  That's what the help is showing.

A positional does not define the arguments of an optional.  The `add_argument` statements are separate.  Omit this `add_argument` if you aren't defining a positional Action.

In:

```
parser.add_argument('-a', '--add', help='add sudo item', nargs='*',
                dest="ldap_attrs")
```

`dest` specifies the attribute name in `args`, e.g. `args.ldap_attrs`.  Without it the attribute would be `args.add` (the first long flag). And the usage would be

```
[-a [ADD [ADD ...]]]
```

I suspect you want to use `metavar`

```
parser.add_argument('-a', '--add', help='add sudo item', nargs='*',
                dest="ldap_attrs", metavar=('dn', 'class'))
```

With a '*', it only accepts 2 metavar strings.

Comment: perfect, that did it.